yupバリデーションで(File|null)[]をチェックする
File型またはnullの配列のバリデーションを実施したいのですが型エラーになってしまい解消ができません。
期待値は配列内の項目ごとにnullであればエラーが返ってきて欲しいです。
型 'ObjectSchema<{ files: (FileList | undefined)[]; }, AnyObject, { files: ""; }, "">' を型 'ObjectSchema<{ files: (File | null)[]; }, AnyObject, any, "">' に割り当てることはできません。
  'default(...).fields.files' の型は、これらの型同士で互換性がありません。
    型 'Reference<unknown> | ISchema<(FileList | undefined)[], AnyObject, any, any>' を型 'Reference<unknown> | ISchema<(File | null)[], AnyObject, any, any>' に割り当てることはできません。
      型 'ISchema<(FileList | undefined)[], AnyObject, any, any>' を型 'Reference<unknown> | ISchema<(File | null)[], AnyObject, any, any>' に割り当てることはできません。
        型 'ISchema<(FileList | undefined)[], AnyObject, any, any>' を型 'ISchema<(File | null)[], AnyObject, any, any>' に割り当てることはできません。
          型 '(FileList | undefined)[]' を型 '(File | null)[]' に割り当てることはできません。
            型 'FileList | undefined' を型 'File | null' に割り当てることはできません。
              型 'undefined' を型 'File | null' に割り当てることはできません。

const fileList: (File | null)[] = [File, File, null, null]
validateTest(validationT)
      .validate(fileList, { abortEarly: false })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("success")
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error")
      })


export const validateTest = (
  t: TFunction<string | readonly string[], 'test'>
): yup.ObjectSchema<{
  files: (File | null)[]
}> => {
  return yup.object().shape({
    files: yup
      .array()
      .of(
        yup
          .mixed<FileList>()
          .test(
            'is-file-or-null',
            'Each item must be a File or null',
            (value) => {
              return value !== null && value instanceof File
            }
          )
      )
      .required('Files array is required')
      .defined()
  })
}

